# symfony/doctrine to sql express error 264 when trying to insert a row

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, sql-server-express

context: building an angular/symfony web app with a sqlexpress database.

Client MUST keep his sql database as administration will still be done through the .net program.

Doctrine unable to properly reverse engineer DB.
Added mapping and entity parameters and functions by hand.

Have been able to insert, update, and delete in most tables, but insertion into one of the tables gives me error 264, seeming to imply it's not able to send an email?..

no trigger on table in question. Can retrieve rows from table through doctrine no problem.
Is there somewhere else in the DB that a "trigger" to send an email could be placed?

Comment: 264 error generally means The column name '%.*ls' is specified more than once in the SET clause. A column cannot be assigned more than one value in the same SET clause. Modify the SET clause to make sure that a column is updated only once. If the SET clause updates columns of a view, then the column name '%.*ls' may appear twice in the view definition. Show your entity so its possible to debug it more.

Comment: I get that but there's nothing really I can tell without looking at your entity and query.

Comment: This is highly unreadable. Consider reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: lol dude, I truly appreciate your help, I do. I am new to posting here, and i tried entering the entity, but it was 60000 chars long and I guess 30000 is maximum length. also, cannot even add replies as I have like no points lol

Comment: ok, read it, agree and understand. this question I guess is totally in left field. will use your original comment to try and troubleshoot. all I wanted was a lead, and you gave me that. appreciate your time. would not know how to make this question simple and direct, let alone how to reproduce it...

Comment: Try running a trace on your query to find the exact field you are repeating on your query. that way you can nail it down. The error is very simple to debug. But without the code I cannot really help. Sorry and good luck.